# Unable to override some Shoelace dialog header CSS

Tags: shoelace

I have tried adding some styles to the panel header of the shoelace dialog. I could add a base style for the entire dialog., but adding a custom class to shadow root DOM is not actually taking it. Here's the code of what I am trying to do

[Adding custom style to the element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdYXZ.png)

[Base styles for the dialog which is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyDRg.png)

[Custom styles which is not applying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL1vc.png)

All these styles are kept in a external css file.

What I can do to make it work? Please let me know. Thank you.